# Print dinamicamente URL da página de posts no WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Como fazer um `echo` na URL da página de posts quando o WordPress está configurado para exibir uma página como Homepage e os posts em uma página específica? Por exemplo:

Em **Configurações > Leitura** é possível definir uma página estática e uma página de posts. O que eu preciso é saber se há uma função que pegue a página de posts de forma dinâmica. 
Exemplo: `echo pegue_a_pagina_de_posts();`. 
Resultado: http://url-pagina-post 
obs.: isso só foi um exemplo. É claro que essa função não existe :)

Eu estou desenvolvendo um tema, então não existe outra opção. Preciso selecionar o URL de posts de forma dinâmica.

Answer (score 1):

Achei a resposta. Eu fiz essa mesma pergunta no forum oficial do WordPress e foi me dada a seguinte resposta:

```
get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
```

O código a cima retorna o ID da página de posts. Para obter a URL fica simples. Veja como ficou:

```
<?php echo get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ); ?>
```

Segue link do WordPress Forum: [link](https://br.wordpress.org/support/topic/pagina-de-posts-dinamicamente/#post-76761)